# Has anyone done or does anyone knows of a way to use Delphi/Prism to develop for the Android os?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

Is it somehow possible to use the Delphi language (or Prism if absolutely necessary) to develop programs for the Android platform ?

Any starting point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for the moment, but soon,  check this [link](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/bl/2010/08/20/p1780) for more info about how develop android applications using <strike>the Object-Pascal language</strike> the [Delphi-Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism) programming language (wich is based on the Delphi language), with [MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/).

> ...and will soon be available from our
>   friends at Embarcadero, but it will
>   work with said release. So if you’re a
>   Delphi Prism customer, or just have a
>   fondness for Pascal syntax, keep an
>   eye out here – more info will be
>   available soon, including templates &
>   other support files.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is Delphi for Android, a project by Lennie de Villiers.

Blog:
http://lenniedevilliers.blogspot.com/2010/09/delphi-for-android-sneak-preview-2.html

Screencast:
http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/preview/DAndroid_01.avi

Answer (score 3):

Android applications are Java applications. There is a native SDK which should be use for particular needs and doesn't allow to build full applications, the application API is a Java API. Unless you have specific needs (i.e. portability), the best way to develop Android applications is using Java. IMHO using other tools that usually lag behind the main ones just to code with a different language is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Object Pascal. I don't think it is currently possible. I don't think that crosscompiler exists...

Comment: Why do you think he means Object Pascal?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of working examples in Lazarus [How to create an LCL Android Application](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Custom_Drawn_Interface/Android#How_to_create_an_LCL_Android_Application)